# LocalStorage not set data until component is mounted vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

I'm creating a shopping cart by using `localStorage` I emit an event by `EventBus` from `ProductCard.vue` to my main `App.vue` for globally store data to `localStorage`
then I get those values, from **ProductCard.vue**

#### Product.vue

```html
<template>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="product__btn add_to_cart_btn"
  
    @click.prevent="addToCart(product)"
  >
    Add to cart
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from "../app";

export default {
    name: "ProductCard",

    methods: {
        addToCart(product) {
            this.addCartLoading = true

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.addCartLoading = false

                EventBus.$emit('addToCart', product)
            }, 300)
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I catch this event in my `App.vue` like below

#### App.vue

```html
<script>

export default {
    name: "App",

    data() {
        return {
            shoppingCart: [],
        }
    },

    created() {
       EventBus.$on('addToCart', this.setCartContents)
    },

    methods: {
        setCartContents(product) {
            let productExistOnCart = this.shoppingCart.find(cart => cart.id === product.id)

            if (product !== undefined && product !== null) {
                this.shoppingCart.push({
                   id: product.id,
                   name: product.name,
                   qty: 1,
                   price: product.price,
                   options: {
                      old_price: product.old_price,
                      image: product.image,
                   }
                })

                localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(this.shoppingCart))
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Then I come to my `CartItemsWrapper.vue` component which is showing my all items which added and showing them in a list by `v-for` loop **CartItemsWrapper.vue** problem is here, I delete the item but and it removes from my `this.shoppingCart` and also from `localstorage` but when I re-add some product without refresh the page `localstorage` all deleted value come again in my `cart` it's not completely removed if I refresh the hole page then add something in the cart then okay, how can I remove item completely without refresh the page.? please anybody help me.

#### CartItemsWrapper.vue

```html
<button type="button" class="remove-btn" @click.prevent="removeCart(cart)">
  Remove
</button>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "CartItemsWrapper",

        data() {
            return {
                shoppingCart: [],
            }
        },

        methods: {
           removeCart(cart) {
              let cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'))

              for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
                if(cartItems[i].id == cart.id) {
                   cartItems.splice(i, 1);

                   break;
                }
              }

              localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems))

              this.refreshCart()
           },
       }
   }
```

[here is gif](https://i.imgur.com/kuI4ox6.gifv) you can see it

Comment: in removeCart you don't remove the items from this.shoppingCart in App.vue, so upon adding another it doesn't add it, geeze you should really use vuex, then you don't need most of this parent/child getter/setter/eventbus bloat

Comment: I don't see your code where you are handling removeCart and addToCart in your App.vue file. And alternative to using the event bus like this to change data is to pass the data down via `provide/inject` and then you can access the data directly in the component you need w/o having to prop drill or have to pass up events (aka reverse prop drilling). You could also use Vuex here, but I think that may be a little overkill for such a small connection.

Comment: @brff19 I forgot to add this line `created() {  EventBus.$on('addToCart', this.setCartContents)  },` in my `App.vue` question updated, then I also fire an event from `CartItemsWrapper.vue` where I `removeCart`.?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code I see that while removing the item from the cart you are not removing it from your local state `shoppingCart` on App.vue.
So when you are pushing any new item to `shoppingCart`, the item gets added along with the old values in it.

What you can do is, you may fire an EventBus `EventBus.$emit('removed')` from your `CartItemsWrapper.vue` and remove the item from the `shoppingCart` as well.

Example

```js
// CartItemsWrapper.vue
removeCart(cart) {
  let cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'))

   for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
     if(cartItems[i].id == cart.id) {
        cartItems.splice(i, 1);

        break;
     }
   }

   localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems))
   // Emitting the event
   EventBus.$emit('removed', cart.id)

   this.refreshCart()
 },
```

```js
// App.vue
created() {
  EventBus.$on('addToCart', this.setCartContents)
  EventBus.$on('removed', this.removeCartContent)
},
methods: {
 removeCartContent(cardId){
    this.shoppingCart = this.shoppingCart.filter(item => item.id !== cardId )
 }, 
 ...
}
```